# Excel VBA - find first empty column

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to find last column with data:

```
 finalcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

But I would like to find first empty column, that is, in my case, somewhere before last column with data.

```
 firstemptycolumn = ?
```

Comment: One way `firstemptycolumn =Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Column`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try like this for the first empty column of row 1:

```
finalcolumn  =  1 + .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
```

It is quite the same logic as your code, but you start from the left and you move to the right.

---

There are two cases, where this code will give wrong values:

- if the last column with value is the last column in Excel ("XFD"), then it will return a column, that does not exist;
- if there is no value on the first column at all, it will return the same - 16384 + 1.

Both can be checked this way, working only with Excel versions after Excel 2003:

```
Function GetFinalFirstColumn(wks As Worksheet) As Long

    GetFinalFirstColumn = 1 + wks.Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    
    'Case for empty first row
    'Case for column XFD
    If GetFinalFirstColumn = 2 ^ 14 + 1 Then
        GetFinalFirstColumn = -1
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add 1 to the last column found with data to find the first empty column.

```
finalcolumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
firstemptycolumn = finalcolumn + 1
```

Comment: "find first empty column ... somewhere before last column with data."

Comment: Need to read the question again *"somewhere before last column "*. This is not what OP is looking for :)

Comment: No, I have like 5 columns with data, then 5 empty columns, then again 1 column with data. That code gets me to column (12), but I need to go to column (6).

Answer (score 0):

This will find the first empty column even if it embedded in other data:

```
Sub FirstEmptyColumn()
    Dim i As Long

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
            For i = 1 To Columns.Count
                If .CountA(Cells(1, i).EntireColumn) = 0 Then
                    MsgBox i
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next i
        End With
End Sub
```